# Trying to get message history from a db collection( mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, chat, history

I'm back with my chat system with history, using mongodb, I can't have let's say about the last 20 messages from the db colection, I'm quite sure it is about some filtering to add into the find() routine, but I don't know where  and how to do that here is my piece of code :

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
if(err) throw err;

var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');

console.log("******************************Printing docs from Cursor Each")

collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {
 console.log(doc);
if(doc != null) {
console.log("Doc from Each ");
console.dir(doc);
 }
});
});
```

this code is showing :

---

{ _id: 5488473660eda4ac251d6688,
  message: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' }
and I don't need the _id value, I only want the last 20 messages as result.
Hoping to be clear enough,
Thanks in advance for your help on this ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
   if(err) throw err;
   var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');
   console.log("******************************Printing docs from Cursor Each")
   collection.find({}, {_id: 0}).sort({$natural: 1}).limit(20).each(function(err, doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      if(doc != null) {
         console.log("Doc from Each ");
         console.dir(doc);
      }
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

To write to browser, use the `response` object as follows

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
       if(err) throw err;
       var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');
       console.log("******************************Printing docs from Cursor Each")
       collection.find({}, {_id: 0}).sort({$natural: 1}).limit(20).each(function(err, doc) {
          console.log(doc);
          if(doc) {
             res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
             res.write(JSON.stringify(doc) + "\n");
          }
          else {
             res.end();
          }
      });
    });
}).listen(port, host);
```

Comment: HI, that one does work, thanks, but I get a new problem, I can see the results under the shell console, but I can't see them under the browser.... any hints  please ? thanks ! :)

Comment: this is the last code used, but It doesn't show any results under the browser :(     
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
   if(err) throw err;
var history="";
   var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');
   console.log("******************************Printing docs from Cursor Each")
   collection.find({}, {_id: 0}).sort({$natural: 1}).limit(20).each(function(err, doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      if(doc != null) {
         console.log("Doc from Each ");

history=history+doc+"\r\n";
         console.dir(doc);
      }
   });
});